# How to make middleware to finish asynchronous request to the server and commit to Vuex store before the page loads?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

My middleware uses `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` and stores the user object in the Vuex store in case if it exists. The code works fine, but the page loads before the user object in Vuex store gets set. My another middleware protects certain pages by checking if the user object exists. Thus, if I load `http://localhost:3000/protected`, I would be declined access, but if I first load another page and proceed to `http://localhost:3000/protected` through a `<nuxt-link>` I can access the page.

How do I make nuxt wait for the middleware to setUser before loading pages?

```
export default async function (context, callback) {
    auth.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
        if (user) {
            context.store.commit("setUser", user)
            callback()
        } else {
            callback()
        }
    })
}
```

---

Update:
Plugins approach yields the same result

Comment: You should use a Cookie approach its way faster than loading the auth state on each reload completly new

Comment: @Badgy you mean getting tokens and using rest interface?

Comment: One thing you could do is to display a **spinner** or **skeleton screen** until the `user` has been `set` in the store. You can do this with a `v-if` in your `template` for example

Comment: Why you are using `commit` and not `dispatch`? Am I missing something? From the docs: https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/actions.html

Answer (score -1):

Here you can read an example of authentication in Vue: https://scotch.io/tutorials/vue-authentication-and-route-handling-using-vue-router

Basically you can check authentication before letting user open the protected component. The easiest way to achieve this is using router guards. In your router definitions:

```
{
  path: '/proctected',
  beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
    if (isAuthenticated()) {
      next();
    } else {
      next('/page-to-show-for-unauthenticated-users');
    }
  }
}
```

This guard will protect from entering  `/proctected` url. Here you can check the working codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JwxoMe

More about router guards: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#per-route-guard

Comment: not really what was asked. First off nuxt middlewares execute on beforeEnter too. Second the issue is his auth state change happens on event e.g. onAuthStateChanged